# Strip HTTP/HTTPS/WWW within an IF statement

Tags: php, wordpress

Have a front-end uploader on my site that users can input a URL. So I created an IF statement to show if they do input a URL (clickable), and nothing if they don't. Now I'm trying to strip the `http` or `https`, and `www` if it exists (trying to achieve https//www.link.com > link.com), but don't know where to put. Assuming I use the `str_replace` function.

```
<a href="<?php

if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_url',true) ) {

    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_url',true);

} else {}?>" target="_blank">

<?php

if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_url',true) ) {

    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_url',true);

} else {}?></a>
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the best solution but you could use `preg_replace` to define a pattern that match the http and www.

```
var_dump(preg_replace("#https?:\/\/(www)?\.?#i","","https://www.test.de"));
```

something like this. Another solution is to work with `parse_url` somthing like this:

```
var_dump(parse_url("https://www.test.de", PHP_URL_HOST));
```

but then you have to remove the `www` because it's part of the host.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't create a function like `get_user_submit_url` make your code cleaner.

```
function get_user_submit_url(){
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_url',true) ) {
        $user_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_url',true);
        // Strip domain here
        // Not sure if you only need full path URL or only domain, so I only get the domain
        $user_domain = preg_replace('#^www\.(.+\.)#i', '$1', $parse_url($user_url)['host']);
    }
    return $user_domain;
}
```

So your HTML will be:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_user_submit_url(); ?>" target="_blank">
    <?php echo get_user_submit_url(); ?>
</a>
```